# Valid service account id not being accepted for workflow service account

Tags: google-workflows

I am attempting to deploy a workflow using the https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/workflows_workflow terraform resource and its failing with error:

```
Error: Error creating Workflow: googleapi: Error 400: request contains errors
Details:
[
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
    "fieldViolations": [
      {
        "description": "The referenced service account is not user-managed, please verify the correctness of the service account name",
        "field": "workflow.service_account"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can see from running `terraform plan` that this is the definition of my workflow:

```
  + resource "google_workflows_workflow" "my_first_workflow" {
      + create_time     = (known after apply)
      + description     = "Magic"
      + id              = (known after apply)
      + name            = "myworkflow"
      + name_prefix     = (known after apply)
      + project         = "myproject"
      + region          = "europe-west4"
      + revision_id     = (known after apply)
      + service_account = "projects/myproject/serviceAccounts/service-account"
      + source_contents = <<-EOT

              - postCallBigqueryStoredProcedure:
                  call: http.post
                  args:
                      url: https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myproject/jobs
                      body: {
                                "configuration": {
                                    "query": {
                                    "query": "call mydataset.mystoredprocedure()"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
        EOT
      + state           = (known after apply)
      + update_time     = (known after apply)
    }
```

The error messages is complaining about the service account however I'm certain that the service account named here: **projects/myproject/serviceAccounts/service-account** is valid and exists so I'm clueless as to why I'm getting this error. Googling the error message hasn't turned up anything useful.

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: I believe the API is still broken in 2023 and I can't the email or the full qualified service account name to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that the service account is valid and it exists. When you are referencing it, are you including the full account name including the details after the '@' ie. `7**********-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`?

I was able to replicate this behaviour by using either an incorrect name or a service account name without the full email address.

You must use the complete email address of your service account. Here's a sample of a correct format. I'm currently using Terraform v0.14.7:

```
service_account = "projects/project_id/serviceAccounts/7**********-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
```

Comment: thank you, that solved it. The (false) assumption I was making was that it didn't require the full email address - I think this is due to experience of previously specifying service accounts as "projects/{project}/serviceAccounts/{the-part-of-the-service-account-before-the-@}" (can't remember where I've done that unfortunately). My mistake, thank you.

Comment: It's not your mistake @jamiet, there's actually a problem with the GCP API I think. It says you can use a unique ID or an email, but it appears only an email will work. Take a look here under the service account value: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/rest/v1beta/projects.locations.workflows#Workflow